# jQuery display only pure HTML in HTML excluding htmlentities

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently displaying posts from my database, and this is an example of the 'message' field in my database. The Alice hyperlink links to the user's profile, while the `?&lt;` etc. are all HTML specified by the user themselves.

```
<a href="/profile/Alice">Alice</a> Alice, you there?&lt;strong&gt;are you here?&lt;/strong&gt;
```

Existing js

```
$.get('/getUserPosts?id=2', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(){
        $("#posts").append('<div class="user-post">'+this.content+'</div>');
    });
});
```

As seen above, the link part is in pure html, while the section behind are some html entities. When I'm displaying my code on my webpage via jQuery, it's showing all HTML content.

How can I make it such that it only displays the pure HTML above (Alice hyperlink), and the html entities (`?&lt;`are you here?`&lt;`) remain in text form? (But still visible)

> Current display [Note that @Alice is a hyperlink]: @Alice Alice, you
>   there? **are you here?**
>
> Expected display [Note that @Alice is a hyperlink]: @Alice Alice, you
>   there? `<strong>`are you here?`</strong>`

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using append to include them in divs.

Comment: Largely depends on where the HTML is being converted in the first place. You could convert them back but that would be intensive. So ideally you want to make sure when you retrieve them, they are not escaped.

Comment: I would just serve it straight up! http://jsfiddle.net/kgs4w62q/

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I'm using .append() and they'll display as html anyway.

Comment: What about this?! http://jsfiddle.net/kgs4w62q/1/

Comment: @RobSchmuecker This is weird. jsfiddle shows it working the way I want it to be, but when I run it on my site, it's showing the user-inputted HTML. Any idea why?

Comment: Show us the code you are using exactly.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I've included my existing js code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81645/discussion-between-rob-schmuecker-and-jas).

Answer (score 0):

It consist in doing this :

```
$('#test').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var t = $this.text();
    $this.html(t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>'));
});
```

Here you go : (made by Jared Farrish)

http://jsfiddle.net/XS5kY/

Comment: Hey, somehow my <a href> links don't work. And does it still show those html entities but in text form?

Comment: Take a look, I've changed it so it works with <a href> : http://jsfiddle.net/XS5kY/257/